# When replacing single image all the other ImageViews are getting replaced in Gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I've `gridview` with 3 cells and each cell will have ImageView and ImageButton to add image from gallery or camera.

But when I'm trying to set selected image in clicked cell of gridview it replacing all cells instead of one single clicked cell.

Here is the adapter for gridview

```
public class Adapter_For_GridView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_For_GridView.ViewHolder>{

    public static final String TAG="===GridView Pics===";
    ViewClickCallback viewClickCallback;
    Context context;
    List<UserGrid> userGridList;
    UserGrid userGridWrapper;
    String ImageData;

    public Adapter_For_GridView(ViewClickCallback viewClickCallback,Context context) {
        this.viewClickCallback=viewClickCallback;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter_For_GridView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_profile_photo_single_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        Log.d(TAG,"On Create View Holder ");
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_For_GridView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        userGridWrapper=userGridList.get(position);

        Log.d(TAG,"On Bind View Holder- Value of isUpload "+userGridWrapper.isUpload());
        Log.d(TAG,"On Bind View Holder Image Data "+ImageData);
        Log.d(TAG,"On Bind View Holder Position "+position+" "+"User Grid Wrapper "+userGridWrapper);
        Log.d(TAG,"On Bind View Holder User Grid Wrapper Get Image Path "+userGridWrapper.getImagePath());

        if (ImageData!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Image Data is Not Null  "+ImageData);
            userGridWrapper.setUpload(true);
            if (userGridWrapper.isUpload()){
                holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp);
                Picasso.with(context).load(ImageData)
                        .into(holder.imageView);
            }
        }
        else{
            holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Value at GetItemCount of GridList "+userGridList.size());
        if (userGridList!=null){
           return userGridList.size();
        }
        return 2;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton imageButton;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG,"On View Holder");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.User_Pics);
            imageButton= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Image Button Clicked "+getAdapterPosition()+" Get Layout Position  "+getLayoutPosition());
            if (viewClickCallback!=null){
                Log.d(TAG,"ViewClickcalleback is not null ");
               viewClickCallback.viewClicked(getAdapterPosition()+1);
            }

        }
    }

    public void setUserGridList(List<UserGrid> userList ){
        this.userGridList=userList;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String path,int position){ //GETTING IMAGE HERE FROM ONACTIVITYRESULT TO THIS ADAPTER
        this.ImageData=path;
        Log.d(TAG,"Position of Grid "+position); //POSITION OF CLICKED ITEM
        Log.d(TAG,"Set Image Path "+path);    //IMAGE PATH OF SELECTED IMAGE
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

LogCat from onactivityresult

```
01-31 18:13:47.917 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: User Profile On Activity Result Calling 25 -1
01-31 18:13:47.927 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: On Activity Result Calling--Request Code 25
01-31 18:13:47.927 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: Intent Data Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/19276 typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 }
01-31 18:13:47.927 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: On Activity Result Position 0
01-31 18:13:48.687 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: Image Name content://media/external/images/media/19276
01-31 18:13:48.687 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===User Profile===: Image /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:48.687 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Position of Grid 0
01-31 18:13:48.687 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Set Image Path /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:48.777 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Value at GetItemCount of GridList 3
01-31 18:13:48.777 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Value at GetItemCount of GridList 3
01-31 18:13:48.777 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Value at GetItemCount of GridList 3
01-31 18:13:48.787 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder- Value of isUpload false
01-31 18:13:48.787 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Image Data /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:48.787 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Position 0 User Grid Wrapper com.example.com.pro_working1.User_Gallery.UserGrid@41c239c8
01-31 18:13:48.787 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder User Grid Wrapper Get Image Path null
01-31 18:13:48.787 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Image Data is Not Null  /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Value at GetItemCount of GridList 3
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder- Value of isUpload false
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Image Data /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Position 1 User Grid Wrapper com.example.com.pro_working1.User_Gallery.UserGrid@41c23e88
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder User Grid Wrapper Get Image Path null
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Image Data is Not Null  /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Value at GetItemCount of GridList 3
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder- Value of isUpload false
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Image Data /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder Position 2 User Grid Wrapper com.example.com.pro_working1.User_Gallery.UserGrid@41c241a8
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: On Bind View Holder User Grid Wrapper Get Image Path null
01-31 18:13:49.557 9146-9146/com.example.com.pro_working1 D/===GridView Pics===: Image Data is Not Null  /storage/sdcard0/pictures/Social/1/Spread-Unconditional-Love_www.example.com-101.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using single varibale **ImageData** for storing the path of selected image. So when views are recreated in gridview this varibale value will be same which will make the first condition true in below code snippet.

```
if (ImageData!=null){
    Log.d(TAG,"Image Data is Not Null  "+ImageData);
    userGridWrapper.setUpload(true);
    if (userGridWrapper.isUpload()){
        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp);
        Picasso.with(context).load(ImageData)
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
}
else{
    holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
}
```

Now as it has entered the first if condition, you are setting upload value to true just before checking its value. Which will again reslut **true**. Hence it is populating all the views with same data.

**Solution**

Change the below method to :

```
public void setImagePath(String path,int position){ //GETTING IMAGE HERE FROM ONACTIVITYRESULT TO THIS ADAPTER
this.ImageData=path;
userGridList.get(position).setUpload(true);
Log.d(TAG,"Position of Grid "+position); //POSITION OF CLICKED ITEM
Log.d(TAG,"Set Image Path "+path);    //IMAGE PATH OF SELECTED IMAGE
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also change the condition check for populating the image :

```
if (userGridWrapper.isUpload()){
    holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp);
    Picasso.with(context).load(ImageData)
            .into(holder.imageView);

}
else{
holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
}
```

Comment: then what should i do.I also have wrapper class with setter and getter methods of `String imageData and boolean isUpload` . What can i do to make `ImageData String` only available to clicked cell

Comment: you can either create **ImageData** varibale in wrapper class, same  as isUpload and then set that varibale to wrapper class object by getting it from list using the position in **setImagePath** method or use **isUpload** boolean falg to diiferentiate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have one path as a field. You assign the new value with `this.ImageData=path;`. After calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` your adapter will refresh it's data and will call `onBindViewHolder()` for each visible item. Then it will load for every call the new image for the path which is `ImageData`.

What you need is a list of paths. You also should check if there's already an image loaded. If it's the same image you won't have to load it again. Maybe you can implement a small cache for this.